# How to send personalized emails using Sendgrid API C#

Tags: c#, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I want to have one API call send to a list of recipients and customize each email. I have the general code worked out. The substitutions are working. But this only sends to the first email address even though I have 2 personalizations with different email addresses.

```
        SendGridClient client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
        SendGridMessage msg = new SendGridMessage();
        msg.SetFrom(new EmailAddress(from, fromName));
        msg.Subject = subject;
        msg.HtmlContent = some content with replacement fields
        List<string> recipients = new List<string>();
        recipients.Add("some address");
        recipients.Add("second address");

        msg.Personalizations = new List<Personalization>();
        for (int x = 0; x < recipients.Count; x++) {
            if (recipients[x].IndexOf("@") > -1) {
                //msg.AddTo(recipients[x]);
                Personalization personalization = new Personalization();
                personalization.Tos = new List<EmailAddress> { new EmailAddress(recipients[x]) };
                Dictionary<string, string> subs = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                subs.Add("[Verification Code]", "ABC123");
                subs.Add("[User Name]", "Mark");
                personalization.Substitutions = subs;
                msg.Personalizations.Add(personalization);
                addressAdded = true;
            }
        }
        Response response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

What am I doing wrong?  Is there some documentation on this?

Comment: Found some docs here https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/personalizations#sending-multiple-emails-from-multiple-senders-to-multiple-recipients

Comment: Did you debug your code and check `recipients[x].IndexOf("@") >-1` is true for all the recipients?

Comment: @Chetan yes I debugged the code.  I also compared it to what happens when you use msg.AddTo(some address), which creates a personalization with that address

Comment: @CharlesHan I've read that document but it does not talk about substitutions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### IsValidEmail Method:

```
    public static bool IsValidEmail(string email)
    {
        try
        {
            var addr = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(email);
            return addr.Address == email;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

#### SendEmail Method:

```
    SendGridClient client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
    SendGridMessage msg = new SendGridMessage();
    msg.SetFrom(new EmailAddress(from, fromName));
    msg.Subject = subject;
    msg.HtmlContent = "<strong> C# is the Best! </strong>";
    List<string> recipients = new List<string>();
    recipients.Add("some address");
    recipients.Add("second address");

    msg.Personalizations = new List<Personalization>();

    foreach (string recipient in recipients)
    {
        if (IsValidEmail(recipient))
        {
            Personalization personalization = new Personalization();
            personalization.Tos = new List<EmailAddress>();

            personalization.Tos.Add(new EmailAddress(recipient));
            msg.Personalizations.Add(personalization);

            Dictionary<string, string> subs = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            subs.Add("{{UserName}}", "Mark");
            subs.Add("{{VerificationCode}}","ABC123");

            personalization.Substitutions = subs;
            msg.Personalizations.Add(personalization);

            addressAdded = true;
        }

        // This Worked
        if (addressAdded)
        {
            Response response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
            Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
            Console.WriteLine(response.Headers.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(response.Body.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I did more testing.  The problem is not that the emails are invalid. But is seems that if the 2 emails are going to the same place you only get one email

Comment: Have you tested this solution? Because it worked fine for me.

Comment: I mean I didn't just add `IsValidEmail()`. please check the code from `// This Worked`

Comment: I tested my original code and it works provided the email addresses don't go to the same inbox. I have 2 different domains that go to the same account

Comment: In any case this is resolved so I'm going to mark this as the answer

Comment: When you call `client.SendEmailAsync(msg)` inside your foreach loop, you'll be sending too many emails. Add all your personalizations/recipients to the `SendGridMessage` and then use `SendEmailAsync` to send the email.
In your answer's code, if `recipients` has 3 email addresses, it'll first send an email to the first email address, then it'll send an email to the first and second email address, then it'll send an email to the first second and third email address.

Comment: @nuander's code looks fine and the issue was probably because they're the same email address. To more easily test, you can try using [subaddressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Subaddressing) if your email provider supports it.